# How use Intent to put a list of data class in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, data-class

I want to send a list of data class (list) for new activity with use of `Intent`. 
In my code below (SplashScreenRepository.kt), first i use retrofit to connect a api (and this is done) and when the response is successful i put the data in list of `DataPeople`.
In second part i need send this list of data for a new activity with `Intent` for put in recycler view. 
So, i wish put all the information in `intent.putExtra`, but how?

DataPeople.kt

```
data class DataPeople(
    val name : String,
    val height : String,
    val mass : String,
    val hair_color : String,
    val skin_color : String,
    val eye_color : String,
    val birth_year : String,
    val gender : String
)
```

SplashScreenRepository.kt

```
fun getDataInApi(onFinnish : (List<DataPeople>) -> Unit) {
        val retrofitClient = NetworkUtils.getRetrofitInstance()
        val endpoint = retrofitClient.create(Endpoint::class.java)
        val callDataOfPeople = endpoint.dataOfPeople()

        val list = ArrayList<DataPeople>()

        callDataOfPeople.enqueue(object : Callback<SerializeDataPeople?> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<SerializeDataPeople?>, response: Response<SerializeDataPeople?>) {
                response.body().let{
                    val note: SerializeDataPeople? = it

                    loop@ for (i in 0..9) {
                        name = note?.results?.get(i)?.name.toString()
                        height = note?.results?.get(i)?.height.toString()
                        mass = note?.results?.get(i)?.mass.toString()
                        hair_color = note?.results?.get(i)?.hair_color.toString()
                        skin_color = note?.results?.get(i)?.skin_color.toString()
                        eye_color = note?.results?.get(i)?.eye_color.toString()
                        birth_year = note?.results?.get(i)?.birth_year.toString()
                        gender = note?.results?.get(i)?.gender.toString()

                        list.add(DataPeople(name, height, mass, hair_color, skin_color, eye_color, birth_year, gender))
                    }
                    dataPeopleList = list
                    onFinnish(dataPeopleList)
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<SerializeDataPeople?>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("onFailure error", t?.message)
                onFinnish(emptyList())
            }
        })
    }
```

SplashScreen.kt

```
class SplashScreenActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var splashScreenViewModel: SplashScreenViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen)

        (...)

        splashScreenViewModel.getIsUpdatingLiveDataLoaded()?.observe(this, Observer{ it ->
            when(it){
                SplashScreenViewModel.States.DONE ->{
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Data is ready.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    splashScreenViewModel.getPeopleLiveData()?.observe(this, Observer {
                        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("list", it)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    })
                }
                (...)
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a Sqlite table using [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) :

DataPeople.kt

```
@Entity
data class DataPeople(
    @PrimaryKey val id :Int,
    val name : String,
    val height : String,
    val mass : String,
    val hair_color : String,
    val skin_color : String,
    val eye_color : String,
    val birth_year : String,
    val gender : String
)
```

DataPeopleDao.kt

```
@Dao
interface DataPeopleDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM DataPeople")
    fun getAll(): List<DataPeople>

    @Insert
    fun insertAll(dataPeople:List<DataPeople>)
}
```

AppDatabase.kt

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(DataPeople::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun dataPeopleDao(): DataPeopleDao
}
```

SplashScreenActivty.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java, "database-name"
        ).build()
    splashScreenViewModel.getIsUpdatingLiveDataLoaded()?.observe(this, Observer{ it ->
            when(it){
                SplashScreenViewModel.States.DONE ->{

                    splashScreenViewModel.getPeopleLiveData()?.observe(this, Observer {
                        //execute this line on a background thread
                        db.dataPeopleDao().insertAll(it)
                        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    })
                }

            }
        })


}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java, "database-name"
        ).build()
    //execute this line on a background thread
    val peopleData = db.dataPeopleDao().getAll()


}
```

## Better Way

You could use Fragments instead of activities and [share data](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating) between them using ViewModel

BUT: 
 I suggest avoiding using :
 2nd approach Singleton could hurt you.
 3rd approach files are always slower than databases.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a significant amount of data you cannot put it in an `Intent` as there are size restrictions. Generally speaking this is the wrong approach. You could try one of the following approaches:

- Put the data in an SQLite database which other activities can access
- Put a reference to the data in a `static` variable which can be accessed by all other activities
- Write the data to a file and have the other activities read the file

Comment: Not a lot of data, the list has 10 positions. Is it still better not to use an intent?

Comment: Generally speaking, i wouldnt send this kind of data in an Intent. If you really want to you will need to implement the `Parcelable` interface for `DataPeople` so that you can put the objects in the `Intent`